# SQLite exception: Database is locked

Tags: sqlite

I have looked into all the questions on the "database is locked" exception but none solve my problem. I have a static function in `DBActions` class that inserts a record in DB as follows:

```
public static class DBActions
{
    // save col, value pairs in DB table
    public static int SaveInDB(string table, string[] cols, object[] vals)
    {
        int resultID = 0;

        string query = $"insert into {table} (";

        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length - 1; i++)
        { // leave the last column coz comma does not follow it
            query += cols[i] + ", ";
        }

        query += cols[cols.Length - 1] + ") values (";

        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            query += $"'{vals[i]}', ";
        }

        query += $"'{vals[vals.Length - 1]}')";
        //MessageBox.Show(query);

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Global.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SQLiteTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        resultID = (int)con.LastInsertRowId;

                        trans.Commit(); // raises the exception
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        return resultID;
    }
}
```

and I am calling this static function whenever I need to save some record in any table like this:

```
Global.StartTime = GetCurrentTimeStamp();

string[] cols = { "SampleID", "OperatorID", "StartTimeStamp"};
object[] vals = { SampleID, CurrentUser, Global.StartTime};
Global.ExpID = DBActions.SaveInDB("ExperimentSettings", cols, vals);
```

When I call it the very first time, it throws the "database is locked" exception. For all others, it executes fine. What could be the possible cause of this? I think all my DB objects are properly being disposed off due to the `using` statements.

Comment: Database is locked usually means that another process (or your own) is currently writing to the database file.

Comment: yeah and as i mentioned, this exception arises on the "very first" insert into DB, subsequent writes using the "same method" give no error and db is updated quite fine. And this is happening on my personal PC so no other processes open/access the DB except my app.

Comment: Then it must be some connection/transaction inside your app.

Comment: Antivirus perhaps? Do you get SQLITE_LOCKED or SQLITE_BUSY exception codes?